# Is there a query language for XML?

Tags: xml

Is there a language that I can use to query an XML document and have result set returned. The same way I can use SQL to query a dtabase and get a result set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and it's called [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/):

> XPath is a language for addressing parts of an XML document, designed to be used by both XSLT and XPointer.

Comment: I've found something called XQuery: http://www.w3schools.com/xQuery/default.asp. Sounds like it might do what I need.